# Using template in class

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to C++, and my question may seem simple.
I can't understand these codes:

```
template<typename a, typename b>
bool operator < (const Pair<a,b> &op1 , const Pair<a,b> &op2)
{
    return (op1.first() < op2.first())
};
```

It seems that operator is a function and its output type is bool. So what is that "template" for? Because this template has been defined before class definition.

```
     template<typename a, typename b>
     class Pair { ...
```

Comment: Function templates do have some special rules about using a type that has been declared, but not been defined yet. In this case, it's legal to have the class definition after the `operator <` function, as long as there's a (forward) declaration of the `Pair` class template *before* the `operator <` function (so that the compiler knows `Pair` is a class template, and not, say, a global variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is that "template" for? - well in that case, it is used to pass a dynamic type parameter to '<' operator, that is basically the use of templates, so that you can declare your class/method only once in yet you can pass different data types to it. In your case, if you don't use template, then you probably would create overloaded methods for each data type that your '<' operator would want to process.

BTW: operator is not a function, it's a keyword for overloading an operator, in this case '<' less than.

Answer (score 2):

The template will substitute in any types where `a` and `b` appear.  This means you don't have to explicitly write the same code to handle `int,double`, `int,int`, `double,int`, `double,double` etc.  Without templates, you'd have to write a function overload for every case, or rely on typecasting.

When you put that template on a whole class, it means the class is specifically built to contain whatever types you give it.  So `Pair<a,b>` can be `Pair<int,double>` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Templates in C++ are a way to define generic classess.

You are right that <strike>an</strike> this operator is a function.

Generic classess allows you to define, well, classess that doesn't specify general types that they use in their methods.

That way you could define `Pair<int, string> param1` and `Pair<int, string> param2` and apply them to `bool resultOfcomparision = param1 < param2`

That would allow you to determine which parameter is bigger based on both `int` and `string` values.

Read more on templates in this [templates guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1)

Comment: This statement is wrong: 'You are right that an operator is a function.' An operator is not always a function, `sizeof` is a great example, it's compile time, not runtime.

Comment: Well, you are right about that. I should have written "this operator" instead general "an operator"